# Print server vs. printer sharing on Windows Server

Tags: printing, windows, print-server, windows-server-2012

On my new Windows Server 2012 I've installed a printer and shared it via the Sharing tab:

[image]

I'm not in a Windows domain (just a regular work group) and printing works fine.

Now there's also the "Print and Ducment Services" role - which includes the "Print Server" role service. Why would I need this role? Or is this just for "advanced" printer deployment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is pretty much what you assume it to be, additional features.  As you have experienced, you'll still be able to share printers and act as a "print server" without the role.  However, the role provides things like the Printer Management console for ease of management, quick deployment through Group Policy (if you were using a AD Domain).  You can also install things like the LDP service for printing from Unix based hosts, and Internet Printing.